# Wordpress, How to change the Post Header Title to display the Post Category?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

In the theme we're using, Mesmerize-Pro, for all posts, it's displaying the post title in two places:

1. The (hero title) header, and
2. The actual post title.

Example: (Link Removed)

I'd love to change the top most hero title to instead display the post category.

I'm able to change the post title to the category, via `functions.php`, but that makes less sense.

Thank you for any help.

-e

Details:

```
.inner-header-description h1.hero-title (Top Title, want to be the Category)

.post-item .post-content-single body #page h1 (Post Title, as is)
```

Comment: Please format code in your question. Also, don't link to an external website but show us what you have done so far by posting a code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the theme, it seems a bit overly complex in how it determines the hero title. If there's no override options in the theme (I didn't install it to check), there does appear to a `mesmerize_header_title` filter you can hook into, it's apparently how they change the title on WooCommerce pages natively in the theme.

One thing to note is that there can be many categories on a post, so typically you'll only want to show the first one. We can use [`get_the_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/) to return an array of [`WP_Term`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term/) objects, and apply the first one to the header title filter:

```
add_filter('mesmerize_header_title', function($title){
    if( is_single() ){
        $categories = get_the_category();
        $title      = $categories[0]->name;
    }

    return $title;
});
```

You should be able to put this in the `functions.php` file and be good to go.

I based this code off the `/inc/woocommerce/woocommerce.php` file that contains the following:

```
add_filter('mesmerize_header_title', function ($title) {

    if (mesmerize_is_page_template()) {
        if (is_archive() && mesmerize_get_current_template() === "woocommerce.php") {
            $title = woocommerce_page_title(false);
        }
    }

    return $title;
});
```

Comment: That did it. 
Thank you so much.
What a relief.  :)